# How to get a model matrix from clmm objects?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models, ordinal, model.matrix

I want to estimate a multilevel ordered logistic model and afterwards access the model matrix. When running a simplified example from `?clmm`:

```
library("ordinal")
mod1 <- clmm(SURENESS ~ PROD + (1|RESP), data = soup)
model.matrix(mod1)
```

I get the error message `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'SURENESS' not found`. From other packages I expected that setting parameters like `model = TRUE` the data going in are also exported to the estimated model, but here all relevant parameters seem to be set accordingly by default. Did I miss some parameters or elements from `mod1` (I went through `attributes(mod1)` but did not find a model matrix.

Strangely if I set a random data.frame, it works:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(y = factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 1000, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE), 
             x = rnorm(1000), 
             id = factor(rep(1:10, each = 100)))

mod2 <- clmm(y ~ 1 + x + (1|id), data = df)
model.matrix(mod2)
```

So what's the difference between `mod1` and `mod2` and how do I get a model.matrix from `mod1`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think model.matrix(mod2) works for clmm objects. However, you can try to build a parallel model for the fixed effects part using functions like 'polr' and apply model.matrix() to the output object. The random-effects part can be fixed separately by using the clmm output.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).